# Convert character column into numeric in HIVE

Tags: hive, casting

I have column name "Color" and it has values that are 2 characters long like "00" or "12" etc.
I need the values in that column to to converted into numeric.

I tried this line of code but it didn't work:
cast ('color' as int)

Any helpful code how to accomplish this in HIVE?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is nearly correct. You just need to remove the quotation mark for the column name: cast(color as int)